# Checking computer working, processes etc

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to know if there is some software to check the computer working,
I mean is the CPU overloaded, is the temperature of motherboard ok, what processes are running etc?
Sometimes I hear the ven working faster so I would like to know what's happening.

Edit: sometimes -> when I watch a Youtube video for example. I hope that the temperatures are not as high as mentioned here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1069851 Interestingly, the ven starts working faster when I go full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which system do you use? If you're using standard Ubuntu, look at the pre-installed System Monitor (type it in the Dash).

Unfortunately, it can't monitor temperature.

Comment: I use 64-bit 14.04.1 LTS version of Ubuntu. I found System Monitor. Thanks. Anyway it looks like I'm not the only one with the Flash problem, hope that the temperatures are not as high as mentioned here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1069851

Comment: what browser are you using and how did you install flash? I am using chromium, with pepperflash installed. I just watched a 1:30 youtube video set to 720P full screen and the fan ran smooth the whole time. Afterwards I ran cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp and it reported 53000 so that would be 53C or 127.4F.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply! I use Firefox which was already installed and I installed Flash using the Ubuntu Software Center. I checked the temperature before watching a Youtube video and it was 55000 (so that I guess is 55C). After watching a video set at 480p for 5 minutes the temperature was already at 74000, 74C...

Answer (score 0):

The utility I use the most is called [System Profiler and Benchmark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/hardinfo/), and it also monitors some temperatures and fans under the heading of "sensors"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use conky, which is used by the majority of Linux users. It can be configured to be quite stylish.

You can monitor the activity of your processors, the temperature and a variety of other stuff. It comes with a variety of preconfigured skins too.

Take a look at [Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky) to know how to setup conky.